# HowTo scale a GPS-Border in Java

Tags: java, gps

How can i scale a GPS-Border by given distance in km in Java. I have a Border-File e.g. Germany where lat, lon is saved in decimal form WGS84. My question is, how can i scale the border by 16km in both directions. I have found a Solution here but this is not working.

```
List<Position> step0 = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < border0.getBorderPainter().getBorder().size(); i++) {
      Position position = border0.getBorderPainter().getBorder().get(i);

      double sfLat = borderData.getDist() / 110.574235;
      double sfLon = (borderData.getDist() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(position.getLat()))) / (110.572833 * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(position.getLat())));

      step0.add(new Position(position.getLon() * sfLon, position.getLat() * sfLat));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem trivial at all. You would need to take every segment of the border, establish a normal for that segment along the spherical surface of the earth, shift the line segment along the normal. Then calculate the intersection of the segment and the two neighboring segments, taking into account that a segment (or any series of segments) may become unnecessary because it's both ends fall withing the expanded area.

Comment: But in case you are trying to detect if a location is within 16km from German border, it may be easier to check if the distance from the given location to any border segments is less than 16km instead of trying to see if a location is inside a single geofence.

Comment: Solved this problem by using JTS